# Send Json Data using Volley from android to server

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to send the array against key to server from android using the Volley http client. But instead of sending array it sends the string. Here is data which I want to send to server.

```
    {"id": "1231241234312",
"steps":[{"id":"123","title":"start"}, {} ] }
```

Steps key contain the array but on server side, it received as string.. HEre is the android code.

```
final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            data.put("id", item.getId());
                            data.put("status", 3);
                            data.put("_action", 1);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        params.put("id", task.getId());
                        params.put("steps", data.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you clearly, Are you asking you want to send the entire json object as string. but now you are sending in key_Value parameters().

Comment: I'm using volley to send data from android to server and volley accept params of Map<String, String> type, thats why I'm using this. I want to send array in steps instead of string. Got my point? @Vishnu Prabhu

Comment: Volley not only accepts params in Map<>. It also accepts body in String. For implementation refer to the JsonRequest<> source code.https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.java

Comment: You can set the body in a string and override the method getBody(), return the bytes from your string.

Comment: Yes but I need the associative array on server. Problem is in associative array which has two keys id and steps, i want to send another array against steps key..

Answer (score 0):

```
private void makeJsonObjReq() {

            showProgressDialog();

            Map<String, String> postParam= new HashMap<String, String>();
            postParam.put("key1", "Value1");
            postParam.put("key2", "Value2");


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.URL_LOGIN, new JsonObject(postParam),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }



    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,tag_json_obj);

}
```

Comment: Is does it accept data as a JsonObject. We have to put the string as a value